# Can somebody explain why this is the result?

Tags: java, debugging

```
public boolean isNumber(String s) {
    String a = s.trim();
    if(a == null || a.isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }
    boolean dFlag = false;
    boolean eFlag = false;
    boolean nFlag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i< a.length();i++){
        char c = a.charAt(i);
        if (c == '+' || c == '-'){
            if (i == 0 || a.charAt(i-1) == 'E' || a.charAt(i-1) == 'e' && i != a.length()-1 && a.charAt(i+1) >= '0' && a.charAt(i+1)<= '0') continue;
            else return false;
        } else if ( c == '.'){
            if ( eFlag || dFlag || (!nFlag && i == a.length()-1) ) return false;
            else dFlag = true;
        } else if (c == 'E' || c == 'e'){
            if (!nFlag|| eFlag || i == a.length()-1) return false;
            else eFlag = true;
        } else if (c >= '0' || c <= '9'){
            nFlag = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

why when the input s = ". 1", the result is true? The second char is whitespace, so it will go into the last else and will return false. I can't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because of

```
} else if (c >= '0' || c <= '9'){
```

you probably want it to be

```
} else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
```

Comment: So is it comparing with asci value ?

Comment: @primitiveType In this case yes

Comment: yes, Thank you very much! I am so careless, I checked it so many times, but I can't even find this small bug!